# Dropdown menu always picks first option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use a dropdown menu to choose options from a list which I get from a SQL query:

```
<div id="container" action="import.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<span id="pickfiles">[Upload files]</span>
</div>

echo ' <form action="import.php" method="post" id="pickfiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Adresslieferant:  <select name="taskOption">
           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Adresslieferanten auswählen</option>';

foreach ($sql as $row) {
echo "<option value=' ".  $row['firma'] . " ' name='adresslieferung' id='adresslieferung' type='text'>".  $row['firma'] ."</option>";
}
echo '  </select>
    </form> ';
?>
```

This is part of a form where I upload a csv file and this code snippet should choose one of the options of the dropdown menu which will be handed over in a javascript code snippet:

```
FileUploaded: function(up, files, info) {
  window.open('import.php?file='+files.name+'&address_delivery='+(document.getElementById('adresslieferung') && document.getElementById('adresslieferung').value ? document.getElementById('adresslieferung').value : ''), '_blank')
    },
```

But this way no matter which option I select at the dropdown menu. It always passes over the first choice of the dropdown menu. I guess it's because it just picks the first one with `id='adresslieferung'` but I don't know how else I could do it.

Comment: add `id` on `<select>` not on `<option>`

Comment: @WM-SH-PD-TV-FC perfect, that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are giving `id` to `<options>` instead of `<select>`, that's why when you try to get data using this `id`, it gives you the first value every-time.

Remove `id` from `<options>` and add it to `<select>`

```
    <div id="container" action="import.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <span id="pickfiles">[Upload files]</span>
    </div>

    echo '<form action="import.php" method="post" id="pickfiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Adresslieferant:
        <select name="taskOption" id='adresslieferung'><!-- added id here-->
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Adresslieferanten auswählen</option>';
            foreach ($sql as $row) {
            //Remove id from options
            echo "<option value=' ".  $row['firma'] . " ' name='adresslieferung' type='text'>".  $row['firma'] ."</option>";
            }
        echo '</select>
    </form>';
?>
```

Note:`jQuery/javascript` treated `id` as a unique attribute so make sure an `id` doesn't use twice in an HTML. You can use `class` concept in case you want to apply some event handling on a bunch of html elements.(give them same `class` and apply event handling in one go)